# Azure CosmosDb Query gives high Rus

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

```
{
        "facilityId": "b554197f-868d-4f22-9115-19f2bc5a356b",
        "vehicleCheckInId": "112b0a43-c6a6-4244-8d80-3859c8ad5d6d",
        "email": "LogiRainTechnology@yahoo.com",
        "vin": {
            "vin": "81413073957539512"
        },
        "vehiclePartialVin": "539512",
        "phoneNumber": "7354656614",
        "technician": {
            "name": "Krutharth Patel",
            "id": "0366949b-15ee-400a-bc39-ca792ef9fecb"
        },
        "advisor": {
            "name": "Abc",
            "id": "01eac7a6-aa21-4f08-a9fa-0449adeae2e3"
        },
       "vehicleDetail": {
            "make": "Rolls Royce",
            "model": "Ghost Series II",
            "trim": "4dr Sedan (6.6L 12cyl Turbo 8A)",
            "year": "2019",
            "colorCode": "#000000"
        },
        "subQueue": [
            {
                "queueId": 2,
                "id": 5
            },
            {
                "queueId": 3,
                "id": 8
            },
            {
                "queueId": 2,
                "id": 3
            }
        ],
        "createdDate": "2020-01-24T11:29:21.1116257Z",
        "entityType": "VehicleStatus",
}
```

Query:

```
select q.id
FROM c JOIN q IN c.subQueue 
where c.facilityId = 'b554197f-868d-4f22-9115-19f2bc5a356b'
AND ((q.id = 5 AND c.advisor.id = '01eac7a6-aa21-4f08-a9fa-0449adeae2e3'
OR (q.id = 8 AND c.techinician.id = '0366949b-15ee-400a-bc39-ca792ef9fecb'))
```

I am executing this query to check the performance of the above document in azure cosmos DB, where I am getting high Rus, where I have 3000 documents for the same facility wise,
I have created a composite index in subQueue.id also, then also I am getting high Rus, is there any other I can write this query or another way to do it.

Comment: You mentioned "high RUs" but didn't mention what the RU cost is. What do you consider "High?" Also, is this a cross-partition query? Do you have more than one physical partition? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Hi, 
Rus Cost 150.25, and i have only one partition key i.e facilityId,
This is not a cross partition query, i am quering in the same document, where i have different status for queues status, while executing the query i reached to above Rus cost which is very high, and i have 3000 documents same as it is